# How to plot 3d directed graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, 3d, adjacency-matrix

I have an upper triangular adjacent matrix which represents a set of nodes which are connected. Every node is defined by three geographical coordinates: x y z.
My goal is to plot the network in order to see what it looks like by taking into account also the direction of the edges.

If I do not take into account the z coordinate, I am able to display the result easily:

[image]

The lines of code to get this result are:

```
A = [0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

 xyz = [ 0  0  0;
      -15 20   5;
       17 24  -3;
       -5 36   7;
      -14 50  -8;
       16 56   3;
        3 70  -1];

F = digraph(A);
figure
p = plot(F,'XData',xyz(:,2),'YData',xyz(:,1)); axis equal;
highlight(p,1,'NodeColor','g'); highlight(p,size(A,1),'NodeColor','r');
view([0 90])
```

How should I modify my code in order to assign to the graph also the z coordinates so I can have a 3d graph? (remember I want to display the edge direction too!!).

What I tried to do is this:

```
p = plot3(F,'XData',xyz(:,2),'YData',xyz(:,1),'ZData',xyz(:,3));
```

but I had no success.

Comment: I guess you have to write a custom `plot3` method. look into the implementation of `plot` for `digraph` (`edit @digraph/plot`) you may find something useful.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @shamalaia your answer is pretty helpful; I am still waiting for more eventual answers and in the case no one else gives other options, I will confirm yours as the right one... btw do you know how to set the arrow head in the middle of the red segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newest MATLAB Release (R2016b), it's now possible to plot a node-link graph in 3d by choosing a different layout method, or specifying x, y and z coordinates directly. In your example, replace the plotting line by

```
p = plot(F,'XData',xyz(:,2),'YData',xyz(:,1),'ZData',xyz(:,3));
```

Resulting plot:

[image: A 3-dimensional plot of the graph data]

Answer (score 3):

Cool problem. I had some spare time and produced this:

```
close all

clear all

A = [0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

 xyz = [ 0  0  0;
      -15 20   5;
       17 24  -3;
       -5 36   7;
      -14 50  -8;
       16 56   3;
        3 70  -1];

    figure; hold on

    for jj=1:size(A,1) %cycle on nodes

        conn=find(A(jj,:)); %find connections for each node

        if numel(conn>0) %if there are non null connections
        for kk=1:numel(conn) %plot them
            a=conn(kk);           

            lh=quiver3(xyz(jj,1),xyz(jj,2),xyz(jj,3),...
             xyz(a,1)-xyz(jj,1),xyz(a,2)-xyz(jj,2),xyz(a,3)-xyz(jj,3),0,'maxheadsize',0.5);

            set(lh,'linewidth',4);
            set(lh,'color',[1,0,0]);

        end
        end
    end
    scatter3(xyz(:,1),xyz(:,2),xyz(:,3),800,'b','.') %plot nodes


   %number the nodes 
   for ii=1:size(xyz,1)
       text(xyz(ii,1),xyz(ii,2),xyz(ii,3),num2str(ii),'Color','k','FontWeight','bold',...
  'FontSize',14, 'HorizontalAlignment','right', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom')
   end


   xlabel('x')
   ylabel('y')
   zlabel('z')

   view(-15,18)
   grid on
```

That I think looks pretty much like what you want:

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want the arrow head to be at the midpoint of the two nodes you can use:

```
line([xyz(a,1) xyz(jj,1)],[xyz(a,2) xyz(jj,2)],[xyz(a,3) xyz(jj,3)],'color',[1 0 0],'linewidth',3)
            lh=quiver3(xyz(jj,1),xyz(jj,2),xyz(jj,3),...
             xyz(a,1)-xyz(jj,1),xyz(a,2)-xyz(jj,2),xyz(a,3)-xyz(jj,3),.5,'maxheadsize',0.5);
```

This draws a line first and the superimpose an arrow that reaches the midpoint (note the `0.5`scaling factor in the `quiver`command):

[image]